# Sales email layout not showing proper Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, transactional-mail

I am using clue theme for Magento 2.3.There is an issue with my all transactional email.

Please check my order email layout.

[image]

If i switch the theme to luma and check order email then it looks fine.

Expected email template like,
[image]

I have called css/email.css in my custom module in using this less CSS. Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_email.less.But it not load into the admin.Please check attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently faced this issue in migrated store. I solved it using dirty hack but it worked for me hope it will work for you too.

I've added all email template related CSS directly into backend.

**At Design->Configurations**

After this remove **pub/* var/*** and generate static content.

After this it started working for me.